# Thessaloniki to Seattle for August 2023

Tags: air-travel, greece, skg

I am hoping someone can explain this to me. I am looking for a 1-stop flight from Thessaloniki (SKG) to Seattle (SEA) for August 2023. All the options that I am getting on Google Flights (or any other website) show layovers > 8 hours. The layovers are in Amsterdam (AMS) or Frankfurt (FRA), and the departing flight leaves later in the day, e.g., AMS to SEA on August 27 leaves at 2:30 pm.

What I don't understand is that if I look for flights to the above example SKG to AMS there is a flight leaving 9:45 AM with Transavia and arrives 11:50AM in AMS. That is sufficient (2:30 hours layover) to catch the Delta flight to SEA at 2:30 PM. I have been to that airport and done that before.

But no website shows this as an option when I put for a 1 stop flight from SKG to SEA. I know I can book these through separate itineraries, but it would be nice to be able to check my luggage all the way to my destination.

Any ideas on what are my options? Also, do airlines release the schedule for August 2023 months in advance or do I have to wait until January for more options to appear?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You seem to have fallen through the cracks here

There aren't a lot of mainline carriers that serve SKG and for some strange reason most flights to the main hubs (Frankfurt, London) leave only in the afternoon which would require an overnight layover.

> there is a flight leaving 9:45 AM with Transavia

Despite being owned by KLM Transavia is not a member of Skyteam. They do offer share itineraries with Delta (at least they used to), but apparently not this one. No idea why.

> Any ideas on what are my options?

It's difficult, but not impossible to find a decent one way option if you have flexibility on the dates. Here is an outbound flight on Aug 11

[image]

The other options are two stops or an overnight layover in Frankfurt, London, etc.

> Also, do airlines release the schedule for August 2023 months in advance or do I have to wait until January for more options to appear?

No point in waiting. Almost all schedules for August are set and the number of new routes will be very small.

Comment: The lack of outbound flights in the morning is probably because no full-service carriers base aircraft at SKG, so they have to come after an inbound flight from somewhere else.  Aegean is an exception, but it seems like they don't have a morning flight to a hub (other than Athens).  Turkish would be my best suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

In Google Flights, select your airports, a random date in August (do just one-way to simplify things), and add filters for “one stop or less” and “layover duration: max 5h” (for instance).

Now click on the calendar, it will show you the days there are matching flights (Mondays, Fridays and Sundays), which are Turkish airlines flights with a 3h15 layover in IST, as already found by Hilmar (but now you now they fly only on certain days of week).